# Need help for a regular expressions with PHP Preg_match to validates a number field on our form

Tags: php, preg-match

:)
We would like to set a special condition (based on PHP Preg_match regular expression) to validates a number on our form.

- That “number field” need, at first, only contain a max of 13 numbers (and only numbers. No letters or anything else).
- The very first number need to be (only) “1” or “2” (not anything else)
- The 4rd and 5rd number represent (the 2 numbers combinated) the “Month of birth” of someone, so the 4rd number need to be "0" or "1", and the 5rd need to be between "1" and "9".

Really appreciates if you can help us for that, to have the good “syntax” for the regular expression in PHP Preg_match to validates that field on our form! :)

Thanks to the community for your support and help!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Here is the literal regex pattern you have described to us:

```
^[12]\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\d{8}$
```

Sample script:

```
$input = "1231212345678";
if (preg_match("/^[12]\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\d{8}$/", $input)) {
    echo "MATCH";
}
```

This regex pattern says to:

```
^                  from the start of the string
[12]               match 1 or 2 as the first digit
\d{2}              then match any digits in the 2nd and 3rd position
(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])  match 01, 02, ..., 12 as the two digit month
\d{8}              then match any other 8 digits
$                  end of string
```